# Loading scripts & styles from a meta box callback function

Tags: forms, wp-enqueue-script, metabox, wp-enqueue-style

#### Case:

I got a set of classes that build form fields based on data from an input array. The class can build the following types of form fields:

- input (basic, hidden, password)
- textarea
- radio
- checkbox
- select
- colorpicker
- datepicker
- file upload

*EDIT:* The class uses `wp_register_script/_style` & `wp_enqueue_script/_style` to load the scripts & styles. The functions containing the actions are hooked inside the class like this: `add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( &$this, 'enqueue' ) );`.

#### Example:

*(Inside `functions.php`)*

```
// meta box callback function
function test_meta_box_cb()
{   
    $input_args = array(
         'type'         => 'color'
        ,'id'           => 'color-id'
        ,'label'        => 'Input Colorpicker Label'
        ,'opt_name'     => 'abc_xyz'
        ,'value'        => '009ee0'
     );
    new FormClass( $input_args, true );
}
// add the meta box
function add_test_meta_box()
{
    add_meta_box( 'test_box', __('TestBox'), 'test_meta_box_cb', 'post', 'advanced', 'high' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_test_meta_box' );
```

#### Problem:

This way, my call for `wp_enqueue_script` & `wp_enqueue_style` doesn't work. I get the form fields rendered, but no scripts or styles.

#### Situation & Backtracing of the problem:

So far I could track down the problem to the wordpress core architecture:

- WP doesn't question what happens inside the callback function until `do_action('add_meta_boxes', $post_type, $post)` get's called (inside *edit-form-advanced.php*).
- That call happens long after *admin-header.php* was called (which contains `do_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', $hook_suffix);`).
- Therefore the script & style can't get loaded (if I'm not wrong).

#### Question:

1. How could i load styles before the meta box form fields get called?
2. How could i avoid repeating the same stylesheet over and over again - i want to use `wp_enqueue_style` & `wp_register_style`?

I'm open to any answers including those who force me to rewrite my class architecture.

*Note:* I need to use this class in a lot of different szenarios, so bundling it to close together with the `add_meta_box` function is not good. I'm close to making an abstraction layer that divides the call for the meta box and the style/script part, but why would I want to add another layer above a core function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is adding the scripts, styles **inside** the class, and because the class instance is created when the hook `add_meta_box` is fired, at that time the `wp_enqueue_script/style` are already finished.

A solution for you is adding the scripts, styles **outside** the function and the class. And because meta boxes are used only at editing pages, you can do as the following:

```
// the editing pages are actually post.php and post-new.php
add_action('admin_print_styles-post.php', 'custom_js_css');
add_action('admin_print_styles-post-new.php', 'custom_js_css');

function custom_js_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style('your-meta-box', $base_url . '/meta-box.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('your-meta-box', $base_url . '/meta-box.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
}
```

Actually, I wrote a [meta box class for WP](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box/), that uses another approach. Instead of writing form class for form fields like you did, my class is a wrapper for meta boxes. If you interested in, it's worth to take a look.

Comment: @Rilwis Glad you dropped by. I know your class (and it's great), but have been completely forgotten to take a look for "inspiration". Needless to say that your article/tutorial/manual is amazing. :)

Comment: @kaiser: Thanks. I hope to listen your opinion about the code, though. Btw, can you share your form class? Does it look similar to scribu's framework? scribu's framework is good, but it lacks documentation and seems a bit complicated.

Comment: @rilwis Sorry to say, but currently I'm not sharing for an easy reason: I'm writing it for our company and sharing code for fields that interfer with the database are a possible security hole (so I'm simply not allowed). Furthermore it takes it data from xml files, so it won't be of much use for most of the people. But i share other stuff on my github page (check my profile). You can find breadcrumb classes, pagination (currently the old version) and other stuff. Just make shure you check the gists too.

Comment: @rilwis About your code: It's written pretty good. My only "problem" with it is that you have to extend the class and have to write your own validation. Imho it would be nice if it offers some basic validation (so text stays text, color stays integer, etc.). But what shall i say: It works and it rocks :)

Comment: @rilwis I now accepted your answer as you have the lowest reputation (and therefor benefit most from it). Non of the answers solved my problem, but afaik it can't be done from inside the `add_meta_box` action hook.

Comment: dead link for meta box class

Comment: @knutole just fixed the link

Answer (score 2):

You should really hook you scripts to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action and your styles to the `wp_print_styles` action.  Inside your functions, do a check to make sure you're on the page using your meta boxes before actually using `wp_enqueue_script()` or `wp_enqueue_style()`.

For example, in one of my plugins I have:

```
public static function enqueue_scripts_and_styles() {
    if( is_admin() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'media-upload' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'thickbox' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'thickbox' );
    } else {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-publication-archive-frontend', WP_PUB_ARCH_INC_URL . '/front-end.css', '', '2.0', 'all' );
    }
}
```

And I hook that to `init` (which fires just before all the other scripts and styles are enqueued).

Comment: @EAMann Point is that I'm doing **exactly** the same inside my class. Point also is that these won't get fired and added to the appropriate hooks until the meta box get's printed - which is much too late (right in the middle of the admin screen). See _Edit_ under _Case_.

Comment: My argument was to not use the meta box callback for this.  Hook things up separately, then add some logic inside your filter to make sure the page will be using your meta boxes.

Comment: @EAMann In this case i missunderstood you. The problem still is that I don't want to separate the calls, so I'm searching for a solution that works with `add_meta_box` as well. The class is extremly generic and I don't want to add a layer above `add_meta_box` just to make it work.

Comment: The problem you're going to run into is that there *isn't* a solution that works with `add_meta_box` directly.  You either have to add a layer on top of it, or queue up your scripts and styles separately.

Comment: Well, there's no way to do it with hooks ... you could just output the scripts and styles directly within your markup. But that's a bad idea for a whole slew of other reasons. Just remember, the `add_meta_boxes` action is fired to directly add markup to the page, not to queue up additional code for the `<head>`.

Comment: One idea I was thinking about, was intercepting `$wp_meta_boxes`, checking for all the core meta-boxes in their places/priorities, and if more is present, check for a flag(?) if it comes from my classes. Then investigate if it contains fields that need js & stylesheets. Problem is not only the concept and that it relies on "core will never change", but also that you would have to do it the old way again and hook into `admin_init` instead of `add_meta_boxes`.

Answer (score 1):

In current form your code dumbs down object to kind of function call (get created, do something, die). Such usage won't do if you want object to do something long before that object is created and destroyed.

Instead of creating object inside of metabox content I'd do following:

1. Create object some time early.
2. Use object's method to deal with scripts.
3. Use another object's method as meta box callback.